# Returning distinct values in either column X or Y in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How do I select DISTINCT values from a combination of two columns?  I am creating a threaded inbox, much like the iPhone SMS system and I want to do something along the lines of:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (senderid or recipientid - whichever value != my $userid),
name, body FROM messages
WHERE $userid = (either senderid, recipientid - whatever is discovered first).
```

Sorry that's so confusing, but the idea is to return the latest message (regardless of whether the message was sent or received) to create distinct threads in the messaging system.  Only 1 thread can exist between two users.

***EDIT***: Here's the code I'm now using

```
// Pull all the girls who are being followed by $userid

$sql = "SELECT * FROM messages
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN '$userid' != senderid 
    THEN senderid ELSE recipients
    END otherid, users.username AS sendername, messages.body, messages.time 
    FROM messages 
    WHERE messages.recipients = '$userid' OR messages.senderid = '$userid'
) subq ON users.id = subq.otherid 
ORDER BY subq.time";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has the [case expression](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) so you can try

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE when $userid != senderid then senderid
                else recipientid end someid /*senderid or recipientid - whichever value != my $userid*/,
                name, body    
FROM messages
WHERE $userid = senderid
    or $userid = recipientid;
```

---

```
Select *
from messages
left join (SELECT DISTINCT CASE when $userid != senderid then senderid
                    else recipientid end someid /*senderid or recipientid - whichever value != my $userid*/,
                    name, body    
             FROM messages
             WHERE $userid = senderid
             or $userid = recipientid) subq
    on messages.userid = subq.someid;
```

*Note that I haven't tested this syntaxt in MySQL - I don't have an instance to work on* ...but using the column name `someid` shouldn't be a problem, since I made the query where it exists into a subquery of something else.

Comment: This looks really promising, I was never taught about the case expression!  I'll give this a shot - what is someid meant to represent?

Comment: `someid` is the column name you give to the result of the case expression. I wasn't sure what you'd want to call it, so  I went with something generic.

Comment: Hey Frustrated, one last question:  When I use the case statement above(which was perfect - thanks!) how do I do a leftjoin based on someid?  Essentially I want to do this: `LEFT JOIN users on users.id = someid`

Comment: Great edit!  Thanks.  Can't quite get it working yet (the first version, without the subquery, worked - just not this one yet).  I'll keep tinkering and I edited my original question with the code I'm now using!

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
select distinct xx from
(
select distinct col1 as xx from mytable
union
select distinct col2 as xx from mytable
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use case statements in the select to check if your $userid is equal to senderid or recipientid and then use the other.

Answer (score 1):

assuming that either the senderid or the recipientid will always match, I would do the following:

select if(senderid == $userid, senderid, recipientid) as user, name, body from messages